# Change/update the key of an object dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an object class that I use as a key into a python dictionary.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CompWord:
    c: str
    length: int

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.c)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.c == other


_ = lambda: defaultdict(_)
d = _()
for compword1 in [CompWord('a', 1), CompWord('b', 2)]:
    key = d[compword1]
    for compword2 in [CompWord('c', 1), CompWord('d', 2)]:
        key = key[compword2]
```

at this point, `d` is

```
CompWord(c='a', length=1)
        CompWord(c='c', length=1)
                CompWord(c='d', length=2)
CompWord(c='b', length=2)
        CompWord(c='c', length=1)
                CompWord(c='d', length=2)
```

I want to update the key in this dictionary if I come across it again only if the length of CompWord is greater than length of key that is already in the dictionary. For example, CompWord(a, 4) > CompWord(a, 1), so I want to update this key with CompWord(a, 4), while also preserving the nested dictionaries under CompWord(a, 1).

Expected output after I update CompWord(a, 1) to Compword(a, 4)

```
c_word = CompWord('a', 4)
if c_word in d:
    # update d[c_word] with new key CompWord(c_word.length, <old length 1>)
```

```
CompWord(c='a', length=4)
        CompWord(c='c', length=1)
                CompWord(c='d', length=2)
CompWord(c='b', length=2)
        CompWord(c='c', length=1)
                CompWord(c='d', length=2)
```

I need to able to reference the length of the old key above which is 1, but I am not sure how I get access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've edited your post a bunch since I started writing my answer, and I don't really feel like reading through your post again...

I'd suggest implementing `__lt__` and using `max()`:

```py
@dataclass
class CompWord:
    c: str
    length: int
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.c)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.c == other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.length < other.length
```

Now accumulate keys to replace:

```py
keys_to_replace = []
for key in d:
    if key == c_word:
        keys_to_replace.append((key, max(key, c_word)))
```

Now replace keys:

```py
for old_key, new_key in keys_to_replace:
    d[new_key] = d.pop(old_key)
```

Also, I'd recommend returning `self.c == other.c` in your `__eq__` as that is more explicit.

EDIT:

I suggest implementing a recursive `key_replacer()` function if you want to drill down into a deeply nested dictionary, as your edits suggest.

I also think it might not be a good idea to `__hash__` and `__eq__` on only one of the values of your dataclass. That seems like a recipe for headaches during debugging.